# How to add columns according to element-wise multiplications

Tags: r

I have a table that contains two columns of numbers. I am trying to generate a new table where the result of each column comes from the element wise multiplication of the previous `data.frame` columns 
For example, i have this:

```
df = data.frame(A=c(2,5,3), B=c(3,2,4))
print(df)

  A B
1 2 3
2 5 2
3 3 4
```

And i need :

```
        3  2   4
    2   6  4   8
    5  15 10  20
    3   9  6  12
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to be clearer? I think you mean you want every element to be the product?

Comment: I want the result to be the sum of each element

Comment: How does 2 and 3 sum to 6? And 5 and 2 to 10? I'm confused by your "And I need" matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a base function, it's called outer () you can choose whether to add, multiply, subtract, etc.

```
outer(A,B,"+")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?. You might need to change how I'm subsetting into A and B though depending on how your data.frame is set up.

```
df = data.frame(A=c(2, 5, 3), B=c(3, 2, 4))
df


element_wise_prod <- function(p_df) {

    # use a more dynamic way to identify the two vectors of your dataframe
    A <- p_df[, 1]
    B <- p_df[, 2]
    result <- t(sapply(A, function(x) x * B))

    return(data.frame(result))
}

element_wise_prod(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
df = data.frame(A=c(2,5,3), B=c(3,2,4))

add_column <- function(df, source_column, value_key){

  modifiers <- df[value_key]  
  # Make names
  value_key <- paste0("value", as.numeric(unlist(modifiers)))

  # Make room
  df[value_key] <- NA
  column_i <- 1

  for(column in value_key){
    result <- df[source_column] * modifiers[column_i, 1]
    # Modify here if you want multiplication or sum
    df[column] <- result
    column_i <- column_i + 1
    }

  return(df)

}
```

Which gives

```
> add_column(df, "A", "B")
  A B value3 value2 value4
1 2 3      6      4      8
2 5 2     15     10     20
3 3 4      9      6     12
```

### Benchmark

Of note, although my answer preserves column names, it is way slower than the other answer posted. See below.

```
library(microbenchmark)


mbm <- microbenchmark("add_column" = {add_column(df, "A", "B")},
"element_wise" = {element_wise_prod(df)})

mbm
> mbm
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max
   add_column 1055.127 1071.859 1125.2072 1088.6105 1188.004 1311.104
 element_wise  131.732  144.879  207.6434  159.3645  174.581 4813.909
 neval
   100
   100
```